# imagemagick command not found?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, imagemagick

I am using Linux Mint 18. The following shows that imagemagick is installed. But how do I use it?

```
$ sudo apt install imagemagick
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
imagemagick is already the newest version (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I've tried this command and it says it's not found

```
$ imagemagick
imagemagick: command not found
```

Any idea how to use imagemagick on command line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

imagemagick is the name of the collection of tools. The individual ones have names like `convert`, `display`, `identify`, `import`, etc. There's a list of all the command-line tools at `man imagemagick`.

Comment: There is no man page for imagemagick in the package (I've installed the package on Ubuntu but OP also have an Ubuntu package). I never realized before, but following the official imagemagick manpage can left a new user puzzled since the doc talks about "magick" and this binary is not included in the latest Ubuntu Package

Comment: This is marked as the answer, but it doesn't actually say where to find the names of these tools (there is no man entry for imagemagick).

Comment: If there is no man pages in for your distro, you can find the list on https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php :D

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, however, I am using a command `magick convert ...` that works on my Windows machine.